# Disable Attribute nor Application Settings on HttpTrigger Azure Function not working

Tags: c#, azure-functions

I've implemented an Azure Function (v2 running on .Net Core 2.2) triggered by an HttpTrigger. Upon specifying either the Disable attribute or using the Application Settings ("AzureWebJobs.Function1.Disabled": "true"), I'm still able to hit this endpoint through Postman. This is **ONLY** happening with HttpTriggers. The ChangeFeed Triggers and QueueTriggers I am also using, are working as expected.

A few things I've tried when running locally:
1. Withing local.settings.json, I've added just the AzureWebJobs..Disabled value
2. I've added the Disable attribute
3. I've added the Disable attribute with a setting defined.

When starting up the function project, the console does show "Function Function1 is disabled."

I've tried it with my local.settings.json as such

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,

  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",    
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet",
    "AzureWebJobs.Function1.Disabled": "true"
  },

  "Host": {
    "LocalHttpPort": 7071,
    "CORS": "*"
  }
}
```

The Function has a general format as such:

```
[Disable, FunctionName("Function1")]
public async Task<IActionResult> RunAsync(
    [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get")] HttpRequest req,
    Binder binder, ILogger log)
{}
```

I would think I would receive a 404 within Postman. Any thoughts, direction, or other information is appreciated.

Comment: which Functions version are you using? There is a difference in how to disable function in v1 and v2: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/disable-function#functions-2x---all-languages

Comment: @silent, I've updated the summary to note the information you are looking for: "v2 running on .Net Core 2.2"

Comment: Hm, I have just tested with an HTTP function myself and can disabled it with the app setting. Can you maybe try to remove the "Disable," in your function header?

Comment: oh, I just realized the only difference to your Function in my sample: Your function is not static. Is there a reason for that? Can you re-test after making it static?

Comment: @silent, I took out the static as I was having issues upon dependency injection. I've created a simple HttpTrigger function in another project where the *static* is still there and removed the Disable attribute. I am told by the console that the function is disabled, but I am still able to successfully hit the function and get a 200. Just to double check, when you tested with an HTTP Function, you sent a request to it via Postman or some other form?

Comment: ah, good point. I actually did not try to hit it... also just saw the log message that it was disabled. Will test that tomorrow. But if thats indeed the behaviour, this looks like a bug that you should report on the Functions github page

Comment: See below. I added another update from the github issue. Seems to work as designed - although not really documented...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could repro your issue as well. Despite the log saying that the function is disabled, you can still call the HTTP trigger. <s>Looks like a bug to me.</s> I opened an issue on Github here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/4764

Update from the github issue:

> Does this only happen when running locally with the CLI (or VS)? Http
>   requests should return 404s unless invoked via an Admin request --
>   this allows the portal to continue to be able to test functions. When
>   running via the CLI, though, I believe all requests are treated as
>   admin requests.
>
> Yes, I can confirm this is indeed different when deployed in Azure.
>   When I use the app setting there AND use the function key (not the
>   master key), the call returns 404.

Comment: Yes, this is just locally with both the CLI and Debug through VS. So it sounds like this is expected functionality locally.

Answer (score 1):

I test local and got the same result as yours, and I found it could not only disable HTTP trigger function, if disable other like Timer function simultaneously, only HTTP could run. But I test with Azure It will respond 404.

So maybe you could use [host.json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-host-json-v1#functions) to disable it, actually it should say run functions you want. If you only have only one or want to disable all functions, you could set the array with null string like below code.

```
{
"functions": [ null ],
"version": "2.0"
}
```

Or like this to only run Function2 then disable Function1 :

```
{
"functions": [ "Function2" ],
"version": "2.0"
}
```

Hope this could help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can also disable by going to the portal:

[image]